# Django custom group permission return 401 code as Unauthorized user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions, user-permissions

I want create user permission based on user group membership.

But next code return next error message "*Request failed with status code 401*".

And for authorized user `print(request.user)` return next line: "*AnonymousUser*".

**permission.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from rest_framework import permissions

def is_in_group(user, group_name):
    try:
        return Group.objects.get(name=group_name).user_set.filter(id=user.id).exists()
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        return False

class HasGroupPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print(request.user)
        required_groups_mapping = getattr(view, "required_groups", {})
        required_groups = required_groups_mapping.get(request.method, [])
        return all([is_in_group(request.user, group_name) if group_name != "__all__" else True for group_name in required_groups]) or (request.user and request.user.is_staff)
```

**views.py**:

```
from .models import AppOne
from .serializers import AppOnesSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from scripts.permission import HasGroupPermission

class AppOneView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = AppOne.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppOnesSerializer
    permission_classes = [HasGroupPermission]  
    required_groups = {
        'GET': ['group1'],
        'POST': ['group1'],
        'PUT': ['group1'],
    }
```

**my User Model:**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

(I tried almost nothing extra, as I'm new one.)

**Edit:**

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ObtainTokenPairWithAgeView
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/obtain/', ObtainTokenPairWithAgeView.as_view(), name='token_create'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from .serializers import MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
class ObtainTokenPairWithAgeView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, cls).get_token(user)
        token['age'] = user.age
        return token
```

Comment: As long as no User is logged in, permissions based on groups are going to fail. The error you are searching is: Why is no User logged in at that stage? We can't help you here since you did not show code on how you log in users.

Comment: Added files. Code was find in someone's project.

Comment: Thx Tarquinius,
Due to your comment I find solution - my problem was that I missed passing user token.

Comment: Great! To improve further read about available methods of the [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/auth/#methods). For example your `def is_in_group` could be written with simply `return group_name in user.groups`. Or your permission checks could be improved by using [`user.get_all_permissions()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_all_permissions). Groups, Permissions and the User model offer a great range of possibilities and more reading (the docs) can spare a lot of writing yourself. You'll find your way, GL